# Is there any information that is missing in this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Q) An advertising agency finds that, of its 200 clients who use Television or Radio or both, 150 use Television. How many use only Radio? **A).** 150, **B).** 100, **C).** 50, **D).** Data is insufficient

According to formula:
$$
n(A \cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A \cap B) 
$$

If $n(A)$ represent number of client using Television and $n(B)$ represents number of client using Radio. Then we have to find $n(B).$

Given information- $n(A \cup B) = 200$ and $n(A) = 150$, then
$$
200 = 150 + x - n(A \cap B) 
$$
and still we don't have values of $n(A \cap B) $. So, I answered option D). Data in insufficient but to my surprise answer is C).50. HOW?

Comment: You are correct: D is the actual answer.

Comment: Can you take a photo of the problem from the book? And cite reference along?

Comment: If your question is 100% accurate, you are correct, data is insufficient. But in case you might have missed something, then the book’s answer is correct. If it is a school book, the printing error chance can be more, but in case if it is a recognised author’s book, the chances that you had missed somethIng in the question here is more.

Comment: @Manikandan I disagree, see my answer.

Comment: @GregMartin I disagree, see my answer.

Comment: No, you do need to find $n(B)$. Set of clients who use radio only corresponds to the set, $(A\cup B) \setminus A$ whose cardinality is simply given by $n((A \cup B ) \setminus A)= n(A \cup B)- n(A)$. The answer written by @user2661923 is correct.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha I think you wanted to write: No, you need ***not*** find $n(B)$.

Comment: @miracle173 yeah..that was a typo..thanks.

Comment: @Manikandan This is complete problem statement, as-is, without any contortion of words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option (c) is correct.

However, you are supposed to assume that of the $200$ people, the number of those people who do not use the TV and do not use the radio is $(0)$.  This is the key and it (arguably) is suggested/indicated by :

"...its 200 clients who use Television or Radio or both, ..."

The phrase does **not** say "...or both, **or neither**".

---

**Edit**
The following edit suggested by subsequent comments:

Normally there are $4$ categories: [1]TV only [2] Radio only [3] TV and Radio both[4] neither TV nor radio.  I interpret the problem as intending that the $(200)$ statistic refers to the union of the first $3$ categories only.

---

Once you accept that, then you infer that the people fall into $3$ categories, and the TV watchers comprise $2$ of the $3$ categories (TV only or TV + radio).

This implies that since what is being interrogated is precisely the 3rd category, radio only, the following computation is valid:

$$200 - 150 = 50.$$

**Edit**
Just to be clear, re my comment following this response:

It is true but irrelevant that the intersection of TV and radio is unknown.  It is irrelevant because that information is not needed to solve the problem.  The $(150)$ people who watch TV comprise the **disjoint** union of those people who only use TV + those people who use TV + radio.  This is precisely the information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no clear information about $n(Television \cap Radio).$ How we can just assume?  Also, it is clearly stated that $n(Television)$ = 150.

Comment: @A.J. It is true but irrelevant that the intersection of TV and radio is unknown.  It is irrelevant because that information is not needed to solve the problem.  The $(150)$ people who watch TV comprise the **disjoint** union of those people who only use TV + those people who use TV + radio.  This is precisely the information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I thought 200 clients who use TV or Radio or Both refers to the whole set as in TV or Radio, the inclusion of the phrase ‘both’ is a tricky one. If you can edit the answer in this way, it will be helpful in much more clarity

Comment: @Manikandan  Normally there are $4$ categories: [1]TV only [2] Radio only [3] TV and Radio both[4] neither TV nor radio.  Clearly the $(200)$ statistic refers to the union of the first $3$ categories only.  I see no other reasonable interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @Manikandan I am unsure what you are referring to by "if you can edit the problem in this way".

Comment: I am a relatively new user @user2661923 in maths. the question was asked by a new user in a simple manner, easy to understand manner in the perspective of a user like me;  in your answer the terminology in the ‘actual question’ was never used. It’s your wish, but a suggestion as understanding the terminology you used is a bit difficult for a relatively new user; nothing more. Thanks. Request you to ignore the conversation if not found in right context

Comment: I am reading this question in these two parts: 1) 200 clients who use Television or Radio or both, and 2) 150 use Television (Only). Also, I have no understanding of Disjoint Union in set theory. Can you provide some link and more information so I can go throw similar problems and concept to understand it.

Comment: @Manikandan It occurs to me that one of my edits was overly harsh.  I softened it.

Comment: @A.J. I interpret the the $(150)$ statistic as intending to represent all people who use tv.  That means that I am interpreting the problem to intend that the $(150)$ statistic represents two groups: those who only use tv and those who use both tv and radio.  The reason that I interpreted the problem this way is that the problem did not say that $150$ use tv only.  Instead, the problem stated that $150$ people use tv.  The word union refers to the collection of elements that are in two different sets.  The word disjoint refers to sets that do not intersect.  ...see next comment.

Comment: @A.J.  For any set $S$ with a finite number of elements, let $|S|$ denote the number of elements, in the set $S$.  For any two sets, $A$ and $B$, each with a finite number of elements, you have that $$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|.$$  The significance of the sets $A$ and $B$ being disjoint (i.e. non-intersecting) is that in that situation, $|A \cap B| = 0.$  It seemed to me that your knowledge of set theory is reasonable, but that you simply misinterpreted the problem.  Anyway, a topic like Set Theory is best explored by a book &/or class.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote because I don't have enough rep to upvote.